# EC2-EBS root storage "Delete on Termination" set to True

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ebs

I have created an EC2 Instance with "Delete on Termination" set to **False** at EBS Root storage. Now, I want to set it to True using AWS CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable delete on termination for EBS:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute \
  --instance-id <...> \
  --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"/dev/sdf\",\"Ebs\":{\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"
```

To enable delete on termination for an instance:

```
aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute \
  --instance-id <...> \
  --instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior terminate
```